# How to modularize Ansible playbook with multiple virtual hosts?

Tags: ansible

<sup>*(EDIT: the question was thoroughly rewritten based on feedback in comments, aiming to follow a suggestion to use "more code, less talk")*</sup>

I've accumulated some ansible playbooks for setting up our host(s). I want to **start modularizing** them. The current situation is roughly like below:

> *docker-registry-playbook.yml:*
>
> ```
> - hosts: foo
>   tasks:
>   - name: install docker
>     # ...
>   - name: copy config files
>     # ...
>   - name: start docker registry
>     # ...etc...
> ```
>
> *issue-tracker-playbook.yml:*
>
> ```
> - hosts: foo
>   tasks:
>   - name: install issue tracker
>     # ...etc...
> ```
>
> *tools-playbook.yml:*
>
> ```
> - hosts: foo
>   tasks:
>   - name: configure nginx virtual hosts
>     copy:
>       src: "{{ item }}"
>       dest: /etc/nginx/sites-available/
>       # ...
>     with_items:
>       - docker.example.com
>       - issues.example.com
>   - name: start nginx
>     # ...
>   - name: configure letsencrypt
>     # ...
> ```

**My first idea was to split it into roles** like below:

```
- hosts: foo
  roles: webserver docker_registry issue_tracker
```

However, in such case, I don't know **how to make the `webserver` role "auto-detect" the host names** (virtual hosts) **it should expose?** I would like to be easily able to move e.g. `docker_registry` role to a different host (`bar`), and have the `webserver` auto-detect the change and update virtual hosts accordingly when I change the new playbook to:

```
- hosts: foo
  roles: webserver docker_registry
- hosts: bar
  roles: webserver issue_tracker
```

I would strongly prefer not having to explicitly list virtual hosts as parameters to `webserver` both on `foo` and `bar`; this would be too much duplication for me. **Is it possible to have `webserver` autodetect names of "virtual hosts"** from the other roles configured on the same server?

Or am I approaching the modularization in a wrong way, and the idiomatic approach in Ansible is to split it along some other axis when modularizing?

---

If not possible to do fully automatically, I'd like it to be done with minimal wiring; I could maybe grudgingly accept something like below, though it already looks *much* too long and ugly to me (but I still don't know how to do this in Ansible):

```
- hosts: foo
  roles:
  - docker_registry
  - role: webserver
    vars:
      vhosts: [ "docker_registry" ]
```

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I can identify with the sentiment of those who did: the question is very meandering and contains more english than yaml, which makes it super hard to identify the actual _question_ you have. So: less talk, more code, is the tl;dr

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Huge thanks for your comment! I tried to rewrite the question thoroughly, guided by the "less talk, more code" hint. Hope it's at least a bit better now...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things! In the `configure nginx virtual hosts` bit, it seems like `tools-playbook.yml` contains the logic for generating the nginx file for every v-host. Have you considered having the roles (e.g. `docker-registry-playbook.yml`) generate their own nginx conf, and then just bounce nginx on change? Because that seems like the only coupling between the "business" role and the webserver one

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Currently, my nginx playbook (tools-...) has a `rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` task; the idea was that this should ensure I don't have leftover sites from some old runs. I like this idea, but it seems incompatible with this approach; is this non-idiomatic for Ansible? I like this extra assurance :/

Comment: Well, doing that can be fine, but it means one cannot cherry-pick a role onto a machine -- the playbook must always include all the roles, and I would actually do it "transactionally" -- stage the config files into a directory and use a `notify:` to "publish" the staging `sites-enabled` into the real one only if the entire playbook runs succesfully

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Why is it necessary to have a common variable *virtual_hosts* in all roles?

> ... Initially, I thought I could set a variable in each of service1 and service2, named e.g. virtual_hosts: and Ansible would merge the duplicated variables into one...

For example:

```
- hosts: foo
  vars:
    virtual_host_service1: docker.example.com
    virtual_host_service2: issues.example.com
    webserver_vm:
      - "{{ virtual_host_service1 }}"
      - "{{ virtual_host_service2 }}"
  roles:
    - webserver
    - service1
    - service2
```

You might want to set the variables in the playbook, or in the host_vars, or in many other places according to the [precedens](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)